# program logic to speed up processing

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, parallel-processing

I have setup an application to parse about 3000 files a day where each contains around 4000-5000 posts in xml format with like 100 fields.
It involves a lot of cleanup and parsing but on average it takes around 6 seconds per post. Now I tried threading but because of the way I have everything set up with variables being overwritten etc...I have divided the files into different folders and just created copies of the program to run and access the assigned folder. It is running on a windows 2008 server with 16 G of memory and I am told I need to reprogram to speed up the process and also not use so much memory.
Does anyone have any suggestions or does this process I have set up seem fine? I am the new guy and literally everyone thinks I am an idiot.

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To fileLists.Count - 1
                   Do
                Try
                  If Not completeList.Contains(fileLists(i).ToString) AndAlso fileLists(i).EndsWith("xml") Then

                        If fileLists(i).Contains("Fa") Then 
                            inputFile = New StreamReader(fileLists(i))
                            data = String.Empty
                            infile = fileLists(i).ToString
                            swriter.WriteLine(infile.ToString)
                            swriter.Flush()
                            Dim objFileInfo As New FileInfo(fileLists(i))
                            fileDate = objFileInfo.CreationTime
                              Dim length As Integer = objFileInfo.Length
                                data = inputFile.ReadToEnd
                                If Not data Is Nothing Then
                                    parsingTools.xmlLoad(data)
                                    tempList.Add(fileLists(i))
                                    completeList.Add(fileLists(i))
                                End If
                                inputFile.DiscardBufferedData()
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
```

Ok I am not sure what code to post because there is literally a lot of code. The above is the main module and onece it reads in data it tries to load it into xml document, if it fails it parses it using ordinary text parsing. It navigates to each field I need to extract and also connects to a couple of web services to get more content before all this is added together to create a new xml file.

```
        manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
        manager.AddNamespace("a", "http://activitystrea.ms/spec/1.0/")
        Dim nodecount As Integer = xmlParser.getNodesCount(navigator, "x:entry", manager)
        For i As Integer = 1 To nodecount
            statid = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/x:id", manager)
            contentDate = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/x:published", manager)
            template = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/x:title", manager)
            title = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/x:source/x:title", manager)
            ctext = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/x:summary", manager)
            htext = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/a:object/x:content", manager)
            author = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/x:author/x:name", manager)
            authorUri = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/x:author/x:uri", manager)
            avatarUrl = xmlParser.XPathFind(navigator, "x:entry[" & i & "]/a:author/x:link[@rel='avatar']/@href", manager)
        Next
```

Comment: Parallel processing will require *more* memory on such a task, not less. Please post some code.

Comment: is there an alternative I should consider?

Comment: Someone who knows Visual Basic should be able to help you with this. (I didn't even know in which language your were working until you posted the code.)

Comment: thanks for your response though.. I was merely more concerned about whether for performance sake if its better to create processes to do this or use some other logic to divide the work and get it completed as opposed to doing it all in a single process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with something like this is the hard drive itself - depending upon many factors it can act as a funnel and essentially constrict the number of files you are able to interact with on the drive concurrently.

With that said, I'd highly recommend you take a look at the TPL (task parallel library) in .NET v4.0.  It's a framework that vastly simplifies the act of "spreading the work across all the available cores" of your processors.  My computer has dual processors, each with 4 native cores (Intel Xeon's @ 3GHz) which gives me 8 cores.  I have an application that downloads ~7,800 different URL's off the net and analyzes their content.  Depending on the values it finds it will do some additional processing then store the results.  This is somewhat similar to your situation in that we both share a restricting resource (for me it's the network) and we have to manually parse and evaluate the contents of the files we're working with.

My program used to take between 26 to 30 minutes (on average) to process all those files.  This was using a properly implemented multithreaded application.  By switching the code over to the TPL it now only takes 5 minutes.  A HUGE improvement.

Take a look at the TPL and plan on having to make some changes to your code in order to maximize the potential improvements.  But, the payoff can be fantastic if done correctly.

Comment: just to make sure I am covering all areas; by implementing parallel tasks - will all variables used locally and globally be safe without overwrites.

Comment: I would like to resist the temptation to offer an answer in light of the fact we haven't seen your code, but typically global variables that are accessed by multiple threads require synchronized access. Though, I only needed to modify my code a little to take advantage of TPL I used the Parallel Programming with Microsoft.NET by Campbell, Johnson, Miller, and Toub. A quick easy read with lots of examples on how code needs to be structured to take advantage of TPL. Now, I use it everywhere and always design accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Does the application run continuously as a service or is it something you run once/or few times a day? If it doesnt run continuously you could try that and limit the processing to a few concurrent threads.

Comment: it will run all the time as the input files are being created all the time but if all files are processed at a given time then it will sleep. Someone else suggested a create a taskfactory that creates tasks that execute as a process but not sure how this is different. thanks for your response